# Cambiar dinamicamente página en <ui:include src sin recargar página

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo esta estructura de página y quiero cambiar la página del contenido dinámicamente en función de lo que selecciono en el menú.

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ui:insert name="menu"><ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor">                       
         <ui:insert name="contenedor"> <ui:include src="#{Bean.pagina}" />
    </div>          
    <div id="pie">
        <ui:insert name="pie"><ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
    </div>
```

Y lo cargo al hacer click en esta opción que modifica la propiedad pagina de Bean dandole el valor que se le pasa como parámetro:

<p:menuitem value="Opcion1" actionListener="#{Bean.cargarPagina('pagina.xhtml')}" ajax="false"/>

Funciona bien pero al cambiar la página recarga toda la página entera. Quisiera que solo referescara la parte del contenedor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar 'p:ajax' para actualizar el contenedor.

```
<p:menuitem value="Opcion1" actionListener="#{Bean.cargarPagina('pagina.xhtml')}">
    <p:ajax update="contenedor" />
</p:menuitem>
```